# code works for other ide but not in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-c++, constructor, visual-studio-2019

Microsofts VS 2019 doesnt seem to recognise my constructor for "Lebensmittel"
while all other ides do, hell even the online ides have no problem with it.
Is there a way to turn that off or to force VS to run it ?

That what you see here is the solution for the codingexercise i do right now. As you can see some variables are in german, my appologies for that.
The program is an exercise in inheritance. The sub-classes "Lebensmittel" (food)and "Möbel" (furniture) are dirived from the class "Artikel" (goods). The food has an expiry date (haltbarkeit) that is also in the constructor (int haltb) but for some infuriating reason VS2019 doesnt recognise the int parameter in the parameterlist of my constructor and refuses to run the code.

```
#include <iostream>                 // Praeprozessoranweisung

using namespace std;

// Klassendefinition:
class Artikel
{
    // Attribute der Basisklasse muessen als "protected" deklariert werden, damit die abgeleiteten Klassen damit arbeiten koennen
    protected:
        char bezeichnung[20];
        int menge;
        double preis;

    public:
        Artikel(char* bez, double p);
        void einkaufen(int anzahl);
        void verkaufen(int anzahl);
};

// Neue Klassendefinitionen
class Lebensmittel:public Artikel
{
    private:
        int haltbarkeit;
    
    public:
        Lebensmittel(int hatb, char* bez, double p);
        void preis_neu();
};

class Moebel:public Artikel
{
    public:
        Moebel(char* bez, double p);
        void preis_neu();
};



// H A U P T F U N K T I O N
int main()
{
    // Ein Objekt fuer einen Artikel instanziieren
    Lebensmittel bananen(2, "Bananen", 0.75);
    
    // Bananen kaufen
    bananen.einkaufen(2500);
    
    // Bananen verkaufen
    bananen.preis_neu();
    bananen.verkaufen(175);
    
    
    // Ein Objekt fuer einen weiteren Artikel instanziieren
    Moebel schraenke("Schraenke", 250.0);
    
    // Schraenke einkaufen
    schraenke.einkaufen(150);
    
    // Schraenke verkaufen
    schraenke.preis_neu();
    schraenke.verkaufen(25);
    
    return 0;
}


// M E T H O D E N D E F I N I T I O N E N
// Konstruktor
Artikel::Artikel(char* bez, double p)
{
    // Speicherueberlauf vermeiden: Letztes Element auf "Stringende" setzen:
    bezeichnung[19] = '\0';
    // Nur Elemente 1 bis 19 uebertragen:
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
    {
        bezeichnung[i] = bez[i];
    }
    
    preis = p;
    
    menge = 0;
}

void Artikel::einkaufen(int anzahl)
{
    menge += anzahl;
    double kosten = preis * anzahl;
    // Ausgabe
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Der Einkauf von " << anzahl << " " << bezeichnung << " kostet Sie " << kosten << " Euro." << endl;
    cout << "(Einzelpreis: " << preis << " Euro.)" << endl;
    cout << "Sie haben jetzt " << menge << " " << bezeichnung << "." << endl;
}

void Artikel::verkaufen(int anzahl)
{
    // Vermeiden, dass mehr verkauft wird, als vorhanden ist
    if (anzahl > menge) anzahl = menge;
    menge -= anzahl;
    double kosten = preis * anzahl;
    // Ausgabe
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Der Verkauf von " << anzahl << " " << bezeichnung << " bringt Ihnen " << kosten << " Euro." << endl;
    cout << "(Einzelpreis: " << preis << " Euro.)" << endl;
    cout << "Sie haben jetzt " << menge << " " << bezeichnung << "." << endl;
}


// Neue Methoden fuer abgeleitete Klassen
// Konstruktoren
Lebensmittel::Lebensmittel(int haltb, char* bez, double p):Artikel(bez, p)
{
    haltbarkeit = haltb;
}

Moebel::Moebel(char*bez, double p):Artikel(bez, p)
{}

void Lebensmittel::preis_neu()
{
    if (haltbarkeit < 3) preis = 0.5 * preis;
}

void Moebel::preis_neu()
{
    if (menge > 130) preis = 0.75 * preis;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The MSVC compiler is fairly specific in this case about what the problem is.

```
error C2664: 'Lebensmittel::Lebensmittel(Lebensmittel &&)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [8]' to 'char *'
message : Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
message : see declaration of 'Lebensmittel::Lebensmittel'
error C2664: 'Moebel::Moebel(Moebel &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [10]' to 'char *'
message : Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
message : see declaration of 'Moebel::Moebel'
```

The code is passing a `const char *` to a function declared to take a *non-const* `char *`. This is not allowed, and C++ has no automatic conversion or provision to cover such cases. Other compilers should give the same error, provided you run them at a high-enough compliance level.

The fix is to change the constructors of `Lebensmittel`, `Artikel` and `Moebel` to take a `const char *` argument instead of `char *`. This will work out of the box, since none of those constructors is attempting to actually modify the char buffer pointed to.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   For comparison, gcc 10.2 on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) gives the following errors in the original code.

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:44:29: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   44 |     Lebensmittel bananen(2, "Bananen", 0.75);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:55:22: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   55 |     Moebel schraenke("Schraenke", 250.0);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```